# Return all values including NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have two tables in SQL Server 2008, and by doing a `JOIN` I want to get all values, however I get only the values where records exist even though I need the fields with NULL records.

Here is the example on how `tableA` looks like

```
|IPAddress  |DNSRecord|
|192.168.1.1|Test     |
|192.168.0.1|Test1    |
```

`tableB` stores the following records

```
|NetworkAddress|SerialNo |
|192.168.1.1   |1Z5A789DS|
|192.168.0.1   |NULL     |
```

My query to return the fields I need is the following

```
SELECT 
    t1.IPAddress,
    t1.DNSRecord,
    t2.SerialNo,
    t2.IPAddress
FROM tableA t1
JOIN tableB t2 ON t1.IPAddress = t2.NetworkAddress
WHERE
   IPAddress LIKE '%' +@IPAddress + '%'
   AND SerialNo LIKE '%' +@SerialNo +'%'
```

The problem with this query is that I get the following result

```
|IPAddress  |DNSRecord|SerialNo |
|192.168.1.1|Test     |1Z5A789DS|
```

And I would like to get returned the following result instead

```
|IPAddress  |DNSRecord|SerialNo |
|192.168.1.1|Test     |1Z5A789DS|
|192.168.0.1|Test1    |NULL     |
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just add a condition for the case of SerialNo is NULL. 
With your actual condition, this case is rejected from selection

```
SELECT t1.IPAddress,
t1.DNSRecord,
t2.SerialNo,
t2.IPAddress
FROM tableA t1
JOIN tableB t2 ON t1.IPAddress = t2.NetworkAddress
WHERE
IPAddress LIKE '%' +@IPAddress + '%'
AND ( SerialNo LIKE '%' +@SerialNo +'%' OR SerialNo is NULL)
```

Comment: Awesome :D it works :) in 8 minutes I will accept it :) I tried this before but without the brackets and it didnt worked :) thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: happy to help, the brackets enclose the two OR conditions. And the result of the OR is evaluated and applied on the AND global condition.

Answer (score 4):

One alternative:

```
SELECT t1.IPAddress,
t1.DNSRecord,
t2.SerialNo,
t2.IPAddress
FROM tableA t1
JOIN tableB t2 ON t1.IPAddress = t2.NetworkAddress
WHERE
IPAddress LIKE '%' +@IPAddress + '%'
AND coalesce(SerialNo, @SerialNo) LIKE '%' +@SerialNo +'%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this instead:

```
SELECT t1.IPAddress,
t1.DNSRecord,
t2.SerialNo,
t2.IPAddress
FROM tableA t1
FULL OUTER JOIN tableB t2 ON t1.IPAddress = t2.NetworkAddress
WHERE
IPAddress LIKE '%' +@IPAddress + '%'
AND SerialNo LIKE '%' +@SerialNo +'%'
```

See: [OUTER JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms187518%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Cheers.

Comment: For some reason it still gives me the same result, thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT t1.IPAddress,
t1.DNSRecord,
t2.SerialNo,
t2.IPAddress
FROM tableA t1
JOIN tableB t2 ON t1.IPAddress = t2.NetworkAddress
WHERE
IPAddress LIKE '%' +@IPAddress + '%' 
AND (SerialNo LIKE '%' +@SerialNo +'%' OR SerialNo IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, I always use this `INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES` in my query or procedure, when I need the null values

```
  SELECT 
        t1.IPAddress,
        t1.DNSRecord,
        t2.SerialNo,
        t2.IPAddress
    FROM tableA t1
    JOIN tableB t2 ON t1.IPAddress = t2.NetworkAddress
    WHERE
       IPAddress LIKE '%' +@IPAddress + '%'
       AND SerialNo LIKE '%' +@SerialNo +'%'
    INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
```

Comment: What is INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES?

Comment: This is actually the correct answer for sql server 2016+. Although, it is syntactically incorrect. You need to add `FOR JSON AUTO, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES` or `FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES`  at the end of your query (after the where clause).